# click() doesn't return a promise

Tags: intern

click() is documented to return a promise (https://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/module-leadfoot_Command.html#click).

When I try

```
    command
    .findById("pause_button")
    .click()
    .then(function(){alert.isFalse(true,"OK")},
          function(){alert.isFalse(true,"NOK")}
    .end();
```

I expect either OK or NOK would be displayed. But it never occurs.

What is the reason?

Thank you.

Alain.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say what the issue is without seeing more of your test case. One possibility is that the command chain isn't being returned from the test. A functional test should return the command chain so that Intern knows to wait for the commands to complete.

```
return this.remote
    .findById(...)
    .click()
    ...
```

If the command chain isn't returned, Intern will assume the test has finished as soon as the test function completes, and will move on to the next test (or end the WebDriver session if there are no more tests).